# Is there a way to run Minecraft Java Edition on a Surface pro X? (16GB RAM, SQ2 processor)

Tags: microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

I would like to run Minecraft Java edition on my Surface pro X (16GB RAM, SQ2 processor) without a VM. Is there a way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the only requirement is a general version of Java then Microsoft has released [OpenJDK Aarch64](https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk-aarch64/releases), which also seems to be [encouraged by Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/enabling-java-for-windows-on-arm64).

It looks like for the current latest release you will want the `msi` installer at https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk-aarch64/releases/tag/jdk-16.0.1-ga

While it is the JDK, that just means that it includes the developers kit. It should still function as a complete JRE (Runtime Environment) as well.

In the Minecraft Launcher you can go to your game "installations", edit the installation (three dots) and then under "More Options" you can change the Java Runtime from the bundled version to the OpenJDK version from Microsoft.

I do not know *if* this will work well, I do not have a Windows ARM machine, but that is the basic theory of what you should need to do.

In theory it should work, apparently Minecraft on Windows [uses it's own bundled OpenJDK anyway](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/nxvzm4/what_is_openjdk/) so telling it to use the ARM version should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm currently stuck at actually finding the location of the openjdk. At the point where I have to add the file I can't find it. How can I locate it or where is it located? Thanks!

Comment: I would expect either `c:\Java\OpenJDK` or `c:\Program Files\Java` or something similar. Does running the MSI installer not prompt you telling you where it is going to install it? As mentioned I don't have an ARM machine so the MSI refuses to run for me...

Comment: No, the msi installer doesn't reveal any information about the location.

Comment: @jan_lampert alternatively https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download has an `aarch64` zip file which can be downloaded from https://aka.ms/download-jdk/microsoft-jdk-16.0.1.9.1-windows-aarch64.zip and extracted wherever you like so you know for sure where it goes.

Comment: Is it possible that the file name is "jrt-fs.jar"? I started the game with it and nothing happend... But I think it's the wrong file.

Comment: you should be looking for the `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`, most likely in the `bin` folder.

Comment: Now Minecraft won't even start after a reinstall :( I keep trying.

Comment: Are you using the launcher and editing the "Java Runtime" as I mentioned in my answer or are you trying to launch the `jar` file manually?

Comment: I could start the Launcher now but the java.exe file as the Java Runtime but the Game crashes although. So, is there an other option for the Java Runtime file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: https://github.com/adiantek/mc-spx
You will have about 20 - 40 FPS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer in combination of Mokubai's answer is the real solution to the author's question.